# Adding EnviromentalReverb and PresetReverb to mediaPlayer (wav and m4a formats) but the reverb doesn't apply

Tags: java, android

I am working on a simple music app in android and I have tried adding EnviromentalReverb and PresetReverb to mediaPlayer (wav and m4a formats) but the reverb doesn't apply. There is no change when the audio plays. I have checked whether my device supports the reverb using the below code and it does. I have looked at similar questions on stackoverflow but there isn't an answer that works.

```
final AudioEffect.Descriptor[] effects = AudioEffect.queryEffects();
// Determine available/supported effects
for (final AudioEffect.Descriptor effect : effects) {
   Log.d("Effects", effect.name.toString() + ", type: " + effect.type.toString());
}
```

The code used for EnvironmentalReverb and PresetReverb is below

## First try

```
EnvironmentalReverb eReverb = new EnvironmentalReverb(1,0);
eReverb.setReverbDelay(85);
eReverb.setEnabled(true);
mMediaPlayer.attachAuxEffect(eReverb.getId());
mMediaPlayer.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);
```

## Second try

```
PresetReverb mReverb = new PresetReverb(1, 0);
mReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEROOM);
mReverb.setEnabled(true);
mMediaPlayer.attachAuxEffect(mReverb.getId());
mMediaPlayer.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);
```

Both return 0 for setEnabled(true) but neither work on the audio. Can someone please point me in the right direction? I am not sure what is wrong with the implementation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18191740

Comment: Yes I do already have the permissions in the manifest file to MODIO_AUDIO_SETTINGS. I was able to get the equalizer to work.

Comment: @RobertHarvey is there a way to save the file after applying the effects?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question so it can be helpful for someone else. 
I wasn't able to get the PresetReverb to work. The EnvironmentalReverb however was working but to find out whether it was working I had to add seekbars for room level and reverb level so I could alter it in real time.

```
EnvironmentalReverb eReverb = new EnvironmentalReverb(0,0);
mMediaPlayer.attachAuxEffect(eReverb.getId());
mMediaPlayer.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);
```

I enabled the reverb on click of a button and then used seek bars to change the room level and reverb level.